# Shopping Cart Price Rule for 2 items from one category

Tags: ce-1.6.2.0

I need to create a price rule that will apply a discount when 2 items from one specific category are added to the shopping cart.

At the moment I have a rule that specifies the category, and specifies "Total Items Quantity IS 2", but this is wrong, I found in testing. As long as one of the items is from the correct category, then when there are 2 items in the cart, the discount gets applied to the cart. If customer adds 2 items from that category, and another item from a different category, then no discount is applied (logically!).

What I need to allow is a customer to buy any number of items from any category, but when their cart contains 2 items from this specific category, to discount those two items (only those two items, not the entire cart) by 5%.

Here's the current settings:

Conditions:
If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :

```
If an item is FOUND  in the cart with ALL  of these conditions true:
    Category  is  1176 

Total Items Quantity  is  2
```

Actions:
Apply Percent of Product Price Discount (5%)

If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :

```
Category  is  1176
```

Can someone please help me figure out how I should apply this rule.
I am running Magento 1.6.2.

Cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your rule should look like this:
**Conditions:**

```
If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :
   If total quantity  equals or greater than  2  for a subselection of items in cart matching ALL  of these conditions:
        Category  is  22
```

**Action conditions:**

```
If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :
    Category  is  22
```

Replace 22 with your category id.

To be able to set a condition like 'total quantity  equals or greater than  2  for a subselection of items in cart...' you need to select from the dropdown 'Products subselecton'. After that, in the new dropdown you will have 2 options: 'total quantity' and 'total amount'

**Note:** the rule will be applied even if you add to cart only one product from category X (22 in this case) with the quantity of 2.
I've tested this on CE 1.7.0.2 but it should work on 1.6 also.

Comment: Bingo - that's perfect!! Thanks for pointing out the product sub-selection element of setting this up as I wouldn't have guessed at that! :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the products to apply the discount to on the Actions tab, in combination with the conditions you specified this should work.

Comment: Thanks but that's my problem, it isn't working correctly. This must mean my settings for the rule are wrong, but it's not clear to me why? I have the action set to only apply discount to items from the specific category. The problem is the rule conditions where the discount should apply when any 2 items from that category are present in the cart are where it falls down for me. Any clues how to fix this rule would be great :-)

Comment: Can you update your question with the settings you have right now? That will give some more information on what might go wrong.